# Recognise a text by tapping on it in a textField Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am a newbie and want to make a custom class for a `UITextView` where I will be able to get the text by tapping on it within the `UITextView`. How to create Custom `UITextView` class?

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: Do you want to get the selected text within the whole text of the textview?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have created custom textview class and protocol that you need to confirm in your class and implement that method to get text of textview every time when you click textview.

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    weak var delegateCustomTV: CustomTextViewDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.textViewTapped))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func textViewTapped() {
        delegateCustomTV?.preparedText(text: self.text ?? "")
    }
}

protocol CustomTextViewDelegate: class {
   func preparedText(text: String)
}
```

use like i have used below,

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, CustomTextViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var textView: CustomTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.delegateCustomTV = self
    }

    func preparedText(text: String) {
        // You will get your text here when you click on textview
        print(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textView.delegate = self 
    }
```

```
extension YourViewController: UITextViewDelegate
{

     //MARK:- TextView Editing begins Function     

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        //TextView Editing Begin Function
    }



    // MARK:- TextView text replaced Function

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
    {
       //Character changed in textView
        return true
    }



     // MARK:- TextView End Editing function

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {        
       //End editing of textView
    }

}
```

Comment: `self.textView.delegate = self` you can't have this line of code in extension.

Comment: And btw your answer not related to OP question: _How to make that Custom TextView class?_

Comment: I've added this code for any single class because question is for identifying `input text` and i don't think that to identify text by using `customClass` is a good idea :(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get text every time you tap textview you have to add tap gesture

```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textView.delegate = self

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.textViewTapped(_:)))

        self.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


 @objc func textViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
       print(textView.text)
    }
```